# Efficient 2d numpy array construction from 1d array and function with conditionals

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am creating a 2d numpy array from a function applied to a 1d numpy array (which contains a conditional) and would like to know a more efficient way of doing this.  This is currently the slowest part of my code.  x is a 1d numpy array, and the output is a 2d numpy array.  There is a switch to construct a different array element based on whether x is less than or greater than 0.  In the future, there could be an arbitrary number of switches.

```
def basis2(x) :

  final = []
  for i in x :
    if i > 0 :
        xr = 2.0*(i-0.5)
        final.append(np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5*xr*(xr-1.0),-1.0*(xr+1)*(xr-1), 0.5*xr*(xr+1.0)]))
    else :
        xl = 2.0*(i+0.5)
        final.append(np.array([0.5*xl*(xl-1.0),-1.0*(xl+1)*(xl-1),0.5*xl*(xl+1.0),0.0,0.0,0.0]))


return np.array(final)
```

Ideally, I would be able to eliminate the for loop - but so far I have not managed to do this properly, using 'where' for example.  Thanks, for any help.

Comment: Can you split your `x` into two arrays, on where `x<=0` and the other `x>0`?  And then evaluate each expression with a whole array?  What's the essential difference between the two expressions?  Give a sample of `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your function:

```
In [247]: basis2(np.array([1,.5,0,-.5,-1]))                                     
Out[247]: 
[array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0., -0.,  1.]),
 array([ 0.,  0.,  0., -0.,  1.,  0.]),
 array([ 0., -0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
 array([-0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]),
 array([ 1.,  0., -0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])]
In [248]: %hist 245                                                             
basis2_1(np.array([1,.5,0,-.5,-1]))
```

With some superficial changes:

```
def basis2_1(x) :
    xr = 2.0*(x[x>0]-0.5)
    res1 = np.array([0.0*xr, 0.0*xr, 0.0*xr, 0.5*xr*(xr-1.0),-1.0*(xr+1)*(xr-1), 0.5*xr*(xr+1.0)])
    xl = 2.0*(x[x<=0]+0.5)
    res2 = np.array([0.5*xl*(xl-1.0),-1.0*(xl+1)*(xl-1),0.5*xl*(xl+1.0),0.0*xl,0.0*xl,0.0*xl])
    return res1, res2

In [250]: basis2_1(np.array([1,.5,0,-.5,-1]))                                   
Out[250]: 
(array([[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0., -0.],
        [-0.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  0.]]), 
 array([[ 0., -0.,  1.],
        [-0.,  1.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  0., -0.],
        [ 0.,  0., -0.],
        [ 0.,  0., -0.],
        [ 0.,  0., -0.]]))
```

Joining the two subarrays:

```
In [251]: np.hstack(_)                                                          
Out[251]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., -0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0., -0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0., -0.],
       [ 0., -0.,  0.,  0., -0.],
       [-0.,  1.,  0.,  0., -0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0., -0.]])
```

Obviously that needs refinement, but it should be enough to get you started.

For example you might make a `result = np.zeros((5,x.shape[0]))` array, just insert the respective non-zero elements (saving all those `0.0*xr` terms).

Looking at those blocks in `Out[251]`:

```
In [257]: x = np.array([1,.5,0,-.5,-1])                                         
In [258]: Out[251][3:,np.nonzero(x>0)[0]]                                       
Out[258]: 
array([[ 0., -0.],
       [-0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.]])
In [259]: Out[251][:3,np.nonzero(x<=0)[0]]                                      
Out[259]: 
array([[ 0., -0.,  1.],
       [-0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0., -0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vectorized approach that exploits a symmetry:

```
col = np.s_[...,None]

def basis2_v(x):
    h,w = np.arange(x.size)[col],np.arange(3,dtype=np.int8)
    # if the terms for xr are the same as the formulas for xl applied to -xr
    # we can therefore unify the code and apply it to |x|:
    # there are three factors in total each term consists of two of them
    aux = (np.abs(x[col])-w/2)*(2/(1^-(w&1)))
    # the easiest is multiplying all three and then dividing one out again
    aux = -aux.prod(-1)[col]/aux
    # fix degenerate cases
    aux[np.isnan(aux)] = 1
    # finally, we need to embed the terms in a zero matrix
    out = np.zeros((x.size,6),x.dtype)
    # the xor trick maps 2,1,0 to -3,-2,-1 if x>0
    out[h,(-(x[col]>0).view(np.int8))^w[::-1]] = aux
    return out

# make small test
x = np.random.randn(10)
# this should pass
assert np.allclose(basis2(x),basis2_v(x))
```